# Tikz subfigures alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption

I created 5 figures and used subcaption package to align them.
My hope is to put three figures in the above line, and the remaining two is the second line in the center.

[image]

But the current one is, one graph by one line as shown in the following image.
[image]

The code is:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]

        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[above] {$-1$} (s2);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_1}$.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
        (s2) edge[->] node[right] {$-1$} (s4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_2}$.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
        (s3) edge[->] node[below] {$-1$} (s4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_3}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
\\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_4}$.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
    \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
    \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
    \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
    \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

    \path[draw, thick]
    (s1) edge[->] node[above] {$-1$} (s2)
    (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
    (s2) edge[->] node[right] {$-1$} (s4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$G_{C}$.}
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{Example of compatible preferences.}
\label{fig:efficiency}
\end{figure}
```

Could you solve this problem?
I saw these problems about images not about tikz.

The example full code is although it's impossible to give my full code because it's based on a conference style.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,calc,decorations.shapes, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]

        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[above] {$-1$} (s2);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_1}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
        (s2) edge[->] node[right] {$-1$} (s4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_2}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
        (s3) edge[->] node[below] {$-1$} (s4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_3}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_4}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[above] {$-1$} (s2)
        (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
        (s2) edge[->] node[right] {$-1$} (s4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{C}$.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Example of compatible preferences.}
    \label{fig:efficiency}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove the empty lines between the `subfigures`.

Comment: Oh, really? The problem still occurs if we delete empty lines between subfugures.

Answer (score 5):

I will be happy to remove this. Use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]

        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[above] {$-1$} (s2);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_1}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
        (s2) edge[->] node[right] {$-1$} (s4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_2}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
        (s3) edge[->] node[below] {$-1$} (s4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_3}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{c_4}$.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, 0) (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, 0) (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (0, -1.5) (s3) {$s_3$};
        \node[draw, shape = circle] at (1.5, -1.5) (s4) {$s_4$};

        \path[draw, thick]
        (s1) edge[->] node[above] {$-1$} (s2)
        (s1) edge[->] node[below left] {$-1$} (s4)
        (s2) edge[->] node[right] {$-1$} (s4);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$G_{C}$.}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Example of compatible preferences.}
    \label{fig:efficiency}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the problem is not solved while I succeeded by your code in the plain file. I guess the problem may be from two-column by a conference style because the space of width is small. How can I do for this? Changing the scale did not work.

Comment: @Sato Provide a complete example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: @Sato I added a solution.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

A off-topic supplement to answer of @Schrödinger's cat  with some suggestion how to make code more clear and shorter. Main changes are marked with comments in code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, % <--- new
                quotes}      % <--- new
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\tikzset{% <--- common settings of styles for all pictures in figure
    node distance = 11mm and 11mm, % used is relative positioning of nodes
         C/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, thick, ->},
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt, auto}
        }
\newcommand\preference{% <--- here is defined common part of all pictures
\node (s1) [C]              {$s_1$};
\node (s2) [C,right=of s1]  {$s_2$};
\node (s3) [C,below=of s1]  {$s_3$};
\node (s4) [C,below=of s2]  {$s_4$};
                        }
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\preference
\draw   (s1) edge["$-1$"]   (s2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$G_{c_1}$.}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\preference
\draw   (s1) edge["$-1$"]   (s4)
        (s2) edge["$-1$"]   (s4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$G_{c_2}$.}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\preference
\draw   (s1) edge["$-1$"]   (s4)
        (s3) edge["$-1$"]   (s4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$G_{c_3}$.}
\end{subfigure}

         % empty line start new row with pictures
\bigskip % more vertical space between rows of pictures
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\preference
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$G_{c_4}$.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\preference
\draw   (s1) edge["$-1$"]   (s2)
        (s1) edge["$-1$"]   (s4) 
        (s3) edge["$-1$"]   (s4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$G_{C}$.}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Example of compatible preferences.}
\label{fig:efficiency}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]